# Wsdl optional params become mandatory in generated java stub code

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, axis

I am newbie to webservices. 
I have generated the stub from the provided wsdl.
What I have observed is the stub generated code asking me to provide the optional parameters mandatory.
For example this is one of the method in wsdl file.

```
        <complexType name="OPP_BOOK_FACT">
           <sequence>
              <element form="unqualified" name="Descriptions" type="tns:Descriptions" minOccurs="0"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="CustomerID" type="tns:CustomerConfirmationID" minOccurs="0"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="UID" type="tns:UPRID" minOccurs="0"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="Ext" type="tns:ExtAuth" minOccurs="0"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="Partner" type="tns:Partner"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="Subscriber" type="tns:Subscriber"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="FactBook" type="tns:FactBook"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="FactAuth" type="tns:FactAuth"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="Price" type="tns:Price"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="SubseReqData" type="tns:SubseReqData" minOccurs="0"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="FactBundleTemplate" type="tns:FactBundleTemplate" minOccurs="0"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="ContentInfo" type="tns:ContentInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
              <element form="unqualified" name="Discount" type="tns:Discount" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element form="unqualified" name="FactShoppingBasket" type="tns:FactShoppingBasket" minOccurs="0"/>
           </sequence>
        </complexType>
```

Here if you notice for example "CustomerID", "UID" and "Ext" are optional param as the minOccurs="0".
But the generated stub api is as below.

*com.xstg.www.soap.schemas.services.v80.Xaction80Stateful_wsdl.Xaction80StatefulPortType.OPP_BOOK_F
 ACT(Description[] arg0, **Long arg1, String arg2, ExtAuthElement[] arg3**, Partner arg4, Subscriber arg5, 
 FactBook arg6, FactAuth arg7, Price arg8, **SubseReqData arg9, FactBundleTemplate arg10, ContentInfo 
 arg11, Discount arg12, FactShoppingBasket arg13**) throws RemoteException*

It is clear that to invoke this method from client, I have to definitely supply all optional param variables also.
I have used `<axis-wsdl2java>` ant call to generate the stub.

May I know the reason for this? According to me, client stub should not expect me to provide all optional params also.
Please let me know if you need any additional info.

**Update:**
We are using axis-1.4. The above stub was generated using axis-1.4.
I tried the same with axis2. The generated stub is different in axis2. But I need to use axis-1.4 as the old client code was already developed using this version

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to try adding nillable="true".

Like:

```
<element form="unqualified" name="Ext" type="tns:ExtAuth" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Comment: I have tried but no luck. It looks nillable="true" is to say that parameter can take null value or not. There is a nice explanation in the following link about this http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/08/18/xml-schema-nillabletrue-vs-minoccurs0/comment-page-1/